# How do I remove the last item of an array inside of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I remove the last item of an array inside of an array. In this case, I want to remove the null at the end of my array inside of an array. Here's my code

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var arrWithSubArr = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length / size; i++){
    arrWithSubArr.push([]);
  }
  var index = 0;
  var whichSubArr = 0;
  for(whichSubArr = 0; whichSubArr < arr.length / size; whichSubArr++){
    for(i = 0; i < size; index++){
      arrWithSubArr[whichSubArr].push(arr[index]);
      i++;
    }
  }

  return arrWithSubArr;
}

chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4);
```

Comment: I ran your code and I got `[ [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, undefined, undefined ] ]`. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your ultimate goal is to split the original array into a number of arrays each equal to or less than the size specified (in the case that the last sub array will not be equal to `size`).  Rather than removing undefined values that get added in the loop it would be easier to prevent them from getting inserted at all.

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var arrWithSubArr = [];

  var whichSubArr = 0;

  // Using Math.ceil returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to the number
  // In this case your minimum number of sub arrays needed to contain all the items of the original array
  var numOfSubArrs = Math.ceil(arr.length/size);

  // create the empty sub arrays
  for(var i = 0; i < numOfSubArrs; i++){
    arrWithSubArr.push([]);
  }

  for (var i =0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arrWithSubArr[whichSubArr].push(arr[i]);
      // starting with the inital sub array at position 0
      // increment to the next sub array once the current one is equal to the specified size
      if (arrWithSubArr[whichSubArr].length == size){
          whichSubArr++;
      }
  }

  return arrWithSubArr;
}

chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

just the array `length` to `length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the last item in the array and alter the original array. I would use

```
arr.pop();
```